# Beautify ruby removes some contents from my html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2, erb

I am using [Beautify Ruby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) to beautify my html.erb.files via sublime text2 editor. When I beautify my files in sublime text2 using **ctrl + alt + k** command, some contents of my files were removed. I think it is as because of syntax error or misalignment or missing end or missing }bracket in my html.erb file. I want to know where the exact mistake in my html.erb file. As my html.erb file is lengthier I am unable to find it manually. Is there any other way to find it??

Comment: You could remove one part after another from your file, running the beautifier after each change until you find the culprit.

Comment: you not using version control? git ftw!

Comment: @froderik- I cant understand, what you are saying??

Comment: use your browser if there is a syntax error rails will raise an error and point you in a general direction